# JOINS in SQL using AdWorks Example

Tags: sql-server, regex, adventureworks

I'm practicing using AdventureWorks and here's the question:
How many Sales Orders (Headers) used Vista credit cards in October 2002

```
SELECT * FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader        --a
SELECT * FROM Sales.CreditCard          --b

SELECT      
    SUM(a.OrderDate), b.CardType        
FROM        
    [Sales].[CreditCard] b
LEFT OUTER JOIN  
    [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] a
```

I'm not sure how to write this query. I'm new to SQL and this is my first JOIN. Eyes are red...thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues:

- You cannot `sum` dates. You have to use `count` here.
- You must not use an `outer join` here. Use an `inner join`. The reason is that you only want `SalesOrderHeader`s that also have a corresponding `CreditCard`
- You forgot the `where` clause
- A join needs an `on` condition

  select count(*) from
  CreditCard cc inner join SalesOrderHeader so on cc.Id = so.CreditCardId
  where cc.CardType = 'Visa' and so.OrderDate between '2002-10-01' and '2002-10-31'

I guessed the names of the foreign key fields `cc.Id` and `so.CreditCardId` because you didn't indicate this piece of information.